# Validating a string as a positive integer

Tags: validation, vbscript

I'm trying to solve a quite common problem - validating the input to be a positive integer greater 1. What I've tried so far works as long as the input is not in science notation.

I searched quite long on SO for solution but didn't find any for this specific case. So this is my current code:

```
If IsNumeric(objArgs(1)) Then

  If CLng(objArgs(1)) = objArgs(1) Then
    if(objArgs(1) < 1) then
      wscript.echo "2nd parameter must be greater than 1"
    else
      ' move on
    end if
  else
    wscript.echo "2nd parameter is not an integer"
  end if
  else
    wscript.echo "2nd parameter is not numeric"      
end if
```

This works fine when the input is something like `a`, `0`, `-10`, `3.14` and so on.

My problem occures when I enter a (large) number in science notation, like `1E+48`. If I enter this I get a overflow-error on the `CLng()`-function.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> validating the input to be a positive integer greater 1

Validation tasks like this one are the domain of regular expressions.

```
Function IsPositiveInteger(input)
  Dim re : Set re = New RegExp

  re.pattern = "^\s*0*[1-9]\d*\s*$"
  IsPositiveInteger = re.test(input)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
MsgBox IsPositiveInteger("asdf")   ' False
MsgBox IsPositiveInteger("0000")   ' False
MsgBox IsPositiveInteger("0001")   ' True
MsgBox IsPositiveInteger("9999")   ' True
```

Expession

```
^       # start of string
\s*     # allow any number of leading spaces
0*      # allow any number of leading zeros
[1-9]   # require one digit between 1 and 9
\d*     # allow any number of following digits
\s*     # allow any number of trailing spaces
$       # end of string
```

This will recognize any string that qualifies as a positive integer. It will not allow you to see whether the integer that the string represents would fit into one of VBScript's numeric data types.

If such a conversion is necessary for your script then you must apply a range check yourself. This is easily done by lexicographical string comparison.

For a more strict result, remove the parts of the expression that allow leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank your for the the solution and especially for this detailed answer including explaining the expression!

Comment: @bish If you want to allow scientific notation, I must change the expression.

Comment: No I dont want to allow it - everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

CLng is to convert into longs, which max value is 2^31-1.
If you want to test really big number and/or fractionnal numbers,
use CDbl (convert into doubles).

Or do you really want to refer to the non-standard class of really big but still integer ? (i.e. integers > 2^31-1).